# Working with the results of a thread without blocking tkinter

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a minimal tkinter program which analyses some data. Some of the datafiles are quite large, so to ensure that the GUI remains responsive I load the data in a new thread.

How can I run analysis on the data once the thread has terminated?

Some example code is below.

```
import tkinter
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

result = []

def func(result):
    sleep(10)
    ans = 1
    result.append(ans)

class myApp(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()

        self.myButton = tkinter.Button(self, text="Press me!", command=self.onButtonPress)
        self.myButton.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def onButtonPress(self):
        thread = Thread(target=func, args=(result,))
        thread.start()

        self.myButton["text"]=result

app = myApp(None)
app.mainloop()
```

How can I make the button text change only when `func` returns?

Comment: Have you considered simply moving the print statement to the end of `func`?

Comment: @BryanOakley the print statement is just an example. I have updated the original to reflect the original program better.

Comment: There are over 100 questions on this site related to using tkinter with threads. Have you searched for an existing answer on this site?

Comment: _How can I make the button text change only when func returns?_  Update, or call a function to update, right before the return (so pass self.myButton to func).

Comment: @BryanOakley I looked through those with the most relevant titles without finding a relevant solution.

Could I just pass `self` to `func` and then modify it inside?

Comment: @CurlyJoe: no, the problem is a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

multiprocessing has an isalive() function and so you can use Tkinter's after() to query it periodically if you want to switch over

Comment: I am using `threading`, not `multiprocessing`, and Tkinter's `after()` runs a function after a specific length of time, rather than after an event is triggered or a boolean like `isalive` changes. I could create a looped `after()` to repeatedly check `isalive` until the function's return value was ready?